# select option not displaying array of object

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, materialize, ngfor

I have a dropdown in my component. Here is the code of the component:

```
export class MyComponent  {

MyObjectArray: MyObject[] = [];

constructor(private _service: MyService)
}

ngOnInit() {
    this._service.get().do((response): MyObject[]) => {
        this.MyObjectArray = response;

        this.MyObjectArray.forEach((obj) => {
            console.log(obj.Code)
        });
    });
```

My html is:

```
<select>
    <option [value]="obj.Code" *ngFor="let obj of MyObjectArray; let i = index">{{obj.Code}}</option>
</select>
```

And in my service:

```
return this._http.get(_url, this.options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(super.handlerError);
```

I have a `console.log` in my code to verify that the service returned something and I am having results. The issue is why is it not binding on my dropdown. I did inspect element and there are no items in my dropdown.

Oh and one thing, I tried putting the `ngFor` in a `div` with `span` inside, it was working. I just don't understand when I put it on my dropdown it doesn't work.

**EDIT**

Now when I inspect element, I can see my objects. But they are still not appearing in my dropdown. Here is what I changed:

```
this._service.get().subscribe(response => this.MyObjectArray = response);
```

**EDIT**

I also have this code on my `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
$('select').material_select();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
this._service.get().subscribe(response => {
        this.MyObjectArray = response;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('select').material_select();
        },200);
});
```

Code : `$('select').material_select();` should init the select box after value init , or you can init on `ngAfterViewInit` but then you have to `destroy and reinit` on the time you get the data.

You are getting data correctly but the issue is you are initialising the select box before you get the data , so it will not auto update select coz you have already manipulated it with jQuery , you have to reinit , to show updated data.

---

How to destroy select 2 : http://materializecss.com/forms.html

```
$('select').material_select('destroy');
```

---

Comment: If the async operation takes longer then 200ms for some reason, like unexpected latency in the network, then this will not work. It might be acceptable in some cases, but if the application depends on this dropdown to function properly then a more robust implementation is required.

Comment: Man , please read my second para , you can init on viewInit and then reinit on when you get data. @unitario , hope you get your answer

Comment: May I know how to `destroy and reinit` my select?

Comment: Updated my answer , please go through the link also you will get better idea

Comment: @GeraldGonzales You need a way to know when the view and *ngFor has been fully rendered before you instantiate it. Since *ngFor requires some time to complete it will not work simply adding it after the data request is complete. I was struggling with the same problem and in my answer outlines how I solved it. It adds complexity to your application and a simple setTimeout might be all you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try triggering change detection manually:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){...}

this._service.get().subscribe(response => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); // what does this print
        this.MyObjectArray = response;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this but it is still not appearing in the UI.

Comment: @GeraldGonzales can you put a `console.log` like I did in my answer and add the log to your question please?

Comment: It logged the array object.

Comment: @GeraldGonzales can you add what it logged to your question please?

Comment: @GeraldGonzales as you would appreciate it is hard to tell something from that response. What are the contents of those objects when you click on them in the console?

Comment: The contest of those objects are array of my object. Along with their property, say for example name and label. Nothing special I think.

Comment: @GeraldGonzales are those objects also an array? Can you include a `JSON.stringified` version of it to your question? I'll update my answer on how to do it.

Comment: @GeraldGonzales can you also change `{{obj.Code}}` with `{{obj?.Code}}`? And can you remove `[value]="obj.Code"` to try things out?

Answer (score 2):

You have a dropdown which is constructed using asynchronous data. Then you have `$('select').material_select()` which instantiates the select and it options.

The problem is that by the time `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook is executed the `*ngFor` operation is still in process. You can pass the select element it and inspect it yourself, my guess it that it will not have any options listed.

I had a similar issue and I solved it by creating a directive, add a reference to it on the `*ngFor` element, then utilize the built in variable `last` - `let last = last`, and pass that as input to the directive.

If `last === true` then your dropdown is complete and you can instatiate it from the directive using `$('select').material_select()`.

You can also use `setTimeout` in the hopes of there is no latency in the network that holds things up, in which case the dropdown would not work of course.